# how to add weights to a wildcard text index in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I use:
`db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )`

Can I still add non-default weights to some of the fields? how?

Comment: Have you given it a try, like `createIndex({"$**": "text"},{weights:{title:10}},{name:'whatever'})`? I personally have have not tried it however, it seems simple enough to test.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about compound index with a default all fields wildcard, then:

> Wildcard text indexes, as with all text indexes, can be part of a compound indexes. For example, the following creates a compound index on the field a as well as the wildcard specifier:
>
> `db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, "$**": "text" } )`

More details: [Wildcard Text Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes), see second half of the paragraph.

If you need to recreate existing index, then:

> To add or change index options you must drop the index using the dropIndex() method and issue another createIndex() operation with the new options.

More details: [Behaviors of createIndex()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#behaviors)

Comment: I see - but will the following `db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "coffee" } } )` (from the examples) will search for text in the `a` field? because from what I read in the docs it won't. I still want to be able to search "free text" but to have weights on some fields...

Comment: I think you misread, this has nothing to do with field weighting in FTS indecies

Comment: You are right, that was not a exact answer, posting now another and more detailed one.